# Show Stack Overflow tag-wiki information to employers on the Careers site

Tags: feature-request, stack-overflow, tags, jobs, tag-wiki

The Careers site has a great connection to my Stack Overflow activity. My top tags automagically end up being shown on my profile for everyone to see.

> [image]

There they are. Take for example [unity3d](/questions/tagged/unity3d). Now everyone is able to see that it's one of my top tags. Something that might be worth showing off.

Similar tags are shown in job listings as well. Searching for "unity3d" gives me a couple of jobs. Not all that bad, but I would have expected more of them.

> [image]

But wait, I usually refer to it as "Unity". It's just that that tag is already taken on Stack Overflow for something with the same name ([unity](/questions/tagged/unity)). Could it be that....

> [image]

And yes, searching for "unity" reveals plenty of "mistagged" jobs (in a Stack Overflow context) that I might have missed out on. Given that I'm not on the other side, I don't know if my profile is similarly invisible for those employers looking for "unity".

As was confirmed to me, there is currently no link with Stack Overflow tag-wiki information. Would it be possible to include this on the Careers site, so employers are more likely to use the correct "tags"? Perhaps even just the tag-wiki excerpt?

Comment: I admit that it never occurred to me that we'd have this kind of mistagging going on. Sounds like something we should look into fixing for sure! However, I'm not sure showing tag wikis to employers is the right solution here. I mean, would they actually *read* them? Would they be more confused than anything because some tag wikis we have are just weird? Would they even know what a tag wiki is or what purpose it serves?

Comment: @AnnaLear you're probably right. But some indication of "this is what that actually means" would be handy I think. As for the concrete solution ... not all that sure.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On the job listing side, we use the same tagging code as SO does.

[image: unity tag]

So this information is available, however if you type fast, you'll never see it pop up and we don't have the benefit of tons of people viewing the listing that might be able to change the tags to be more appropriate.

On the candidate search side, we use a different solution because the tag selection for candidate search is not the same as it is for job listings (i.e. anything people type into careers can be searched for, not just what exists on SO).

[image: unity candidate search]

This seems more like a general tagging issue across the network than just with careers.  Our candidate search product handles synonyms as they are handled on SO however, so if this is resolved via SO synonyms, it will eventually be reflected in candidate search as well.

Comment: Ah, so it *does* already exist? Hmm. That's somehow disappointing. And I suppose giving me editing privileges is not an option? ;)

Comment: Well we probably wont ever allow people to edit job listings directly, but you can use the "Ask this employer a question" feature at the bottom of the job listing to suggest the change to them.

Comment: Am I overlooking something? I can't seem to find the feature you're referring to ....

Comment: @Bart I can't find that feature either...

Comment: @Bart it's only enabled if they have the apply with your profile feature enabled and you are logged in with an account that has a CV.  My apologies for not looking that up before posting.

Comment: That explains it. Well, thanks for all anyway. :)